# JdbcTemplate update method

Tags: spring, jdbctemplate

I sent a POST request to the Rest Controller.

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String addThisUser(@RequestBody String json)
  {
    String result = "";
    try
    {
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
      result = addUser.addTheUser(jsonObject.getString("firstName"),
              jsonObject.getString("lastName"), jsonObject.getInt("age"),
              jsonObject.getString("email"), jsonObject.getLong("phoneNumber"),
              jsonObject.getString("username"), jsonObject.getString("password"));
    }
    catch(JSONException exception)
    {
      result = "Something went wrong. Try again later";
    }
    return result;
  }
```

I then tried to use JdbcTemplate to insert the values into a table. However it is not working and I cannot figure out why. Here is the code(I am getting a DataAccessException):

```
dbConnecter.update("INSERT INTO userInformation (firstName, lastName, age, email, phoneNumber, username, password) "
            +"VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            new Object[] {thisFirstName, thisLastName, thisAge,  thisEmail, thisPhoneNumber, thisUsername, thisPassword});
    catch(DataAccessException exception)
    {
        output = "Cannot access database";
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        output = "Unknown error";
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would also like to note that the select statement works fine:

```
  String queryString = "SELECT * FROM userInformation";


  List<Map<String, Object>> listOfUsers = dbConnecter.queryForList(queryString);
```

I honestly have no idea why this is happening. Can someone please help?

Comment: Have you an exception stracktrace? If yes, provide it please.

Comment: What's the error displayed?

Comment: What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clear error message would help in providing a better answer. But try this if needed :

```
Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
statement.executeUpdate(updateTableSQL);
```

Comment: I used the PreparedStatement interface and it worked! Thank you so much

Comment: @Maths2468 Glad you found it helpful